# jQuery Keypress Arrow Keys steering in DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with Dropdown, which is connected to the database and I can't control arrows up and down to move result only mouse click.
See this is my code that I started writing but doesn't work. 
What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(field-customer-dropdown).on("keydown", function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.which;
  if (keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 40) {
    showDropDown();
  }
});
```

**Edit**:

As I made my little code currently looks like this:

```html
   $("body").on("keydown", function(event) {
         var keyCode = event.which;
         if (keyCode == 40) {
             console.log("key");
             $(".drop-down-row:firstchild").css("backgroundcolor","red");   
          }

   });
```

And this is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKMFm.jpg)
How should look like the code so that I could push keydown 40 switch from Data 1 on Data 2?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: First of all, `$(field-customer-dropdown)` is invalid. You need to put it inside `$("field-customer-dropdown")` quotes.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript variables cannot contain `-` in them. Also, the selector you are using is not a HTML Tag, which doesn't have any prefix. If it's a `class`, prefix it with `.` else if it is an `id`, prefix it with a `#`.

```
$(".field-customer-dropdown").on("keydown", function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.which;
  if (keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 40) {
    showDropDown();
  }
});
```

Comment: Okey, thakns you very much.
But I don't anderstend how I can fix this bug. Can you help me?